# Permission denied app.log Flask python wsgi apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, logging, wsgi

I have a flask app on Apache server with wsgi.

However, there is a problem with logging.
When I launch the app the apache error log:

```
[Wed Aug 23 15:32:09.743373 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 36533:tid 139899072366144] [client 37.156.216.219:63411] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/suhona-elis/app.log', referer: http://
```

Python log implementation:

```py
log_dir = "/var/www/html/suhona-elis/app.log"

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_dir, filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

os.chmod(log_dir, 0o777)
```

File permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  312 Aug 23 15:25 app.log
```